# SQLite multiple conditions

Tags: sqlite

Suppose I have the following TABLE called "fruits" with the fields "FRUIT", "STATUS", and "DATE"

```
FRUIT       STATUS      DATE
----------  ----------  ----------
apple       ADDED       2017-07-01
orange      ADDED       2017-07-03
peach       ADDED       2017-07-03
apple       REMOVED     2017-07-14
pear        ADDED       2017-07-11
peach       REMOVED     2017-07-15
```

How can I query for all fruits that have been both 'ADDED' and 'REMOVED'?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a self-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT added.FRUIT
FROM fruits AS added
INNER JOIN fruits AS removed
  ON added.FRUIT=removed.FRUIT
WHERE added.STATUS="ADDED"
AND removed.STATUS="REMOVED"
```

This will find all pairs of rows, that share the fruite and have the correct status.

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/63f21/3/0)

Comment: I think you might need to join on the fruit type `Inner join fruits as removed on removed.fruit = added.fruit`

Comment: @Chris added that while you were commenting.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!